# facebook unity sdk 7.9.4, unity 5.4.1, Error building APK, Error: Fail to repackage resources

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk, unity-game-engine

I'm using UNITY 5.4.1 and Unity Facebook SDK 7.9.4, but however, unable to build APK.

```
ERROR: Command Invocation failure: failed to repackage resources.
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
/Users/pb036local/Desktop/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "/Users/pb036local/Desktop/platforms/android-25/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.customtabs:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable -S "
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for a possible error in your App-ID in Facebook->edit settings -> App ID
In my case, it was a blank space at the end of the appID causing the same problem.[faulty app key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIJ5m.jpg)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll see to it.

Comment: It don't resolved. Same error thrown. Welcome new solution on this.